# How to resolve a Unix symlink?

Tags: files-and-directories

Does Mathematica have any function to resolve a Unix symlink (recursively, if necessary) to its real path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If *Mathematica* doesn't have one or if its existence is not immediately evident from the documentation, you can easily whip up an equivalent in under a minute using the operating system's tools. We'll use [`readlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) to resolve the symlink using the `-e` option:

> readlink - print value of a symbolic link or canonical file name
>   ...
>
> **-e, --canonicalize-existing**
>   canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively, all components must exist

```
Clear@readlink
readlink[link_String] := Import["!readlink -e " <> link, "Text"]
```

Mac users might want to install GNU coreutils and use `greadlink` instead of the default that ships with Apple (you might also have to replace the executable above with its full path). As an example, on my system:

```
readlink["~/.vimrc"]
(* "/Users/username/.vim/vimrc" *)
```

If no output is returned, the input was not a valid symbolic link. You can use this to extend the above definition to include error messages, warnings, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  That works well interactively, though it produces a strange error if I run it at startup from my `Kernel/init.m`.  I posted a [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29127/2464) about it.

Answer (score 4):

`FileInformation["filename", "AbsoluteFileName"]`

Complete list of file system object properties: `FileInformation["filename","Rules"]`

Comment: I'm not running a Unix OS but +1 for `FileInformation`!

Comment: `FileInformation` with `AbsoluteFileName` works on Windows as well, resolving Windows Vista/7 symlinks, NTFS junction points, and SUBST drive links.

Comment: librik, I did not mean to imply it didn't; I'm very glad you shared this function!  Rather, I meant that despite the fact that this question centers on Unix, and therefore I cannot test if it is applicable there, I was grateful enough to vote anyway.

Comment: I guess the FileInformation function has gone away sicne this answer was posted?