# "LinkOpen::linke : specified file is not a mathlink executable"

Tags: warning-messages, initialization

The following code runs fine if I run it interactively:

```
Clear@realpath;
realpath[path_] := Import["!readlink "<>path, "Text"];
testsymlink = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "testsymlink"}];
test = realpath[testsymlink];
```

In particular, the variable `test` gets the expected (non-`Null`) value.

The same code runs fine also if I put it in a standalone script and execute it with

```
<< "/path/to/script.m";
```

But if I put the same code, all by itself, in my `Kernel/init.m` file, it fails: the variable `test` gets the incorrect value `Null`.  (The variable `testsymlink`, on the other hand, is still correctly set.)

Furthermore, if I *then* evaluate

```
realpath[testsymlink]
```

*interactively* (in the newly started Mathematica session), I get the error shown in this post's title, twice:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error, but I'm having it may give someone else a clue as to why the snippet is failing in the first place (when run as part of executing `Kernel/init.m`.

PS: It appears that the offending snippet puts the session in a corrupted state, because when I attempted to upload the image shown above, I got this error:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I had first restart Mathematica (after deleting the offending snippet from `Kernel/init.m`), before I could upload these images.

Comment: @kjo I'm passing through an akin pickle http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114041/why-here-does-importfile-produce-an-error-linkopenlinke. Did you find any explanation ?

Comment: @mitochondrial: no, I never did, unfortunately.

Comment: @mitochondrial: I just had a random (and, admittedly, very farfetched) thought: MATLAB files also end in `*.m`, and therefore in some systems, MATLAB is set as the default program for such files.  Could there be a weird interaction between *Mathematica* and the desktop environment that leads *Mathematica* to conclude that a particular `*.m` file is not a "MathLink executable"?  Grasping at straws here...  I'd test this idea myself, but I no longer have access to the system where I got this error.