# Why here does Import[file] produce an error LinkOpen::linke:?

Tags: import

In the folder `$BaseDirectory\\Kernel` I have a file `init.m`, who calls 
a customized initialization package

```
Needs["UserInitialization`","C:\\UserInitialization\\UserInitialization.m"];
```

Having observed strange behaviours of PutAppend (placed in the package), 
ransacking in MSE, an hour ago, I have learned of the unusual parsing 
of the infix form of `PutAppend`, and for a while I have been supposing that what follows could be ascribed to some non standard parsing of Import. But now the occurrence seems less credible.

In `UserInitialization.m`

```
testFile = FileNameJoin[{$UserInitializationFolder ,"aFile.txt"}];
testContent = Import[testFile, "Text"];
```

provokes an error:

```
inkOpen::linke: Could not find MathLink executable. >>
```

Similarly occurs for

```
testFile = FileNameJoin[{$UserInitializationFolder ,"aFile.txt"}];
testContent = Import[testFile];
```

but

```
testFile = FileNameJoin[{$UserInitializationFolder ,"aFile.txt"}];
testContent = Import[testFile, "Lines"];
```

returns what it is supposed to do:

```
{"a content"}
```

## Addendum

A resembling question was asked here: ["LinkOpen::linke : specified file is not a mathlink executable"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29127/linkopenlinke-specified-file-is-not-a-mathlink-executable) but, provided that I'm not misunderstanding, this situation differs in that the code fails even run in interactive mode.

See also [Why can't I import a file in the init.m file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64496/why-cant-i-import-a-file-in-the-init-m-file?rq=1), where useful workarounds are proposed.

I would say that my question has been essentually answered there.

Comment: Which OS and *Mathematica* version are you using and how your `$UserInitializationFolder` is defined? With version 10.4.1 on Win7 x64 I have no problems with the code `Import[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}], "Text"]`.

Comment: @Alexey Pokov Hallo! Mathematica version: 8.0.1.0 OS: Win Xp ver. 5.1.2600